# JavaScript Randomizing Function Not Working in HTML Context but Works Outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In short: as a standalone function, my randomizer works. When put together with HTML and jQuery it doesn't work.

Details: 
I am building a "randomizer" - an HTML `input` gets multiple words separated by a `space` from the user. Let's say it gets 5, 7, 10, 30 words, for example. Then, it returns randomly **only** three of these words to the user.

The idea is that the user input is a single string of many words. Then, the code (should) break down the string into an array of strings (using `.split`) and assign this new array to another variable. Then, this newly created array creates another new array which has only three randomly chosen words. Finally, this last array is what the user should see after clicking on the button.

I am coding that in Atom, saving the HTML/CSS/JS in local files on my laptop (Mac) and then run it on Chrome.

I am using jQuery 3.3.1. from a CDN.

Nature of the problem: 
When HTML and JS run together the randomizer doesn't work - after few button clicks, it happens that I get two identical words which should be the case. It shouldn't be the case because I don't experience the same problem when I test only the JS code with a variable to which I assign few different words in one single string. My guess is that something happens when the jQuery gets the user input. However, I am totally not sure.

I am fighting this for two days now. I tried whatever I could think of.

Is the problem the way I link the JS functions and the HTML code via the jQuery event listener?

Or maybe my function itself is poorly written?

HTML / JS / jQuery code is below:

```js
// Here begins the jQuery code
$(document).ready( () => {

    let $button = $('.button');
    let $userInput = $('#userInputField');
    let $userOutput = $('.userOutput');

    $button.on('click', () => {
      var b = document.getElementById('userInputField').value;
      var a = doEverything(b);
      $userOutput.text(a);
    });

}); // Here ends the jQuery code.

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Here begins the JavaScript code
var coolWords = []; 

function doEverything(aString) {
  var bString = aString.split(" ");
  var finalResult = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < bString.length; i++) {
    coolWords.push(bString[i]);
  };

  newList = coolWords.slice();

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var hey = newList.splice( Math.floor( Math.random() * newList.length ), 1) [0];
    finalResult.push(" " + hey);
  }; // [0] is used so finalResult receives only strings and not whole arrays with only one string in each array.

  return ("Hey, the words are " + finalResult[0] + ", " + finalResult[1] + " and " + finalResult[2] + ".");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="button">
    <input type="text" id="userInputField" value="">
    <button class="button">Magic</button>
  </div>

  <div id="userOutput">
    <p class="userOutput">test</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: You randomizer function looks alright. Maybe you should also add a check for repeating words.

Comment: @TheodorB - but isn't exactly that what `.splice` is for? For each iteration it gets one word from `newList` and saves it in `hey`. Correct?

Comment: Alright, so the problem comes from var coolWords = []; , make sure you reset it ( coolWords = [] ) inside doEverything function.

Comment: Get rid of the `<input>` for testing and add several variables that contain sample input. Develop and test with those first. Also allows others to quickly run your code and for you to narrow down where bugs are. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Your over complicating this function, you use `aString.split(" ");` to create your array, for you only to then iterate this array and add this to an array called `coolWords`,. That you then clone, and randomly select from.   Why not randomly select from you original `split` and be done.?

Comment: @TheodorB, but how can I save all subsequent words added by the user then? That's why I kept `coolWords` as a global variable. Imagine this is a website which you visit weekly and you want to have your previously added information at hand. (does that make sense?)

Comment: Well, then, inside the population loop, you will have to check for the word not to be already added.

Comment: @charlietfl, this is what I do locally, yeah. Thanks for the link, will read it for sure! :)

Comment: `Imagine this is a website which you visit weekly and you want to have your previously added information at hand`   A global variable won't help you there, unless your expecting your users to keep the webpage open for weeks on end.

Comment: @Keith, as I answered TheodorB - I am trying to have a global variable so when the user comes back to the website she can again be able to access the previously added information. Otherwise, I love your idea and have to try it. Do you think there's another way to save the user's input for future sessions?

Comment: If you want to save user data for future sessions, the best solution is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @Keith, how can approach this issue then? Have in mind, I build this for education purposes. I still haven't covered back-end functionality, server requests, etc.

Comment: @TheodorB, what do you call the population loop? Again, am I not doing that using the `.splice` method? I think by using it I am omitting any duplicates. Or not?

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < bString.length; i++) {
    coolWords.push(bString[i]);
  };

Comment: The saving / loading of the list is really another question, and as mentioned you will want to look into `localStorage` for this.  But your main problem currently is your always adding words, even if you have had them before.  So for this let's do a check  `if(coolWords.indexOf(bString[i]) < 0) coolWords.push(bString[i]);`

Comment: @Keith, yeah, I am on it. Together with a whole bunch more. :D

Comment: @Keith, that seems legit. Have to test. Thank you!

Comment: I'll post an answer with that small mod I just mentioned,  the localStorage part isn't too complicated, but unfortunately Snippets on SO are sandboxed and localStorage is blocked.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code updated to work as a Snippet,..

Unfortunately localStorage is blocked in Snippets,.. But the change to make it store in localStorage shouldn't be too hard.

update: Also if you look at the lines I've commented out with localStorage on, they should be what's needed to make your words persistent for your users if they come back.

```js
// Here begins the jQuery code
$(document).ready( () => {

    let $button = $('.button');
    let $userInput = $('#userInputField');
    let $userOutput = $('.userOutput');

    $button.on('click', () => {
      var b = document.getElementById('userInputField').value;
      var a = doEverything(b);
      $userOutput.text(a);
    });

}); // Here ends the jQuery code.

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Here begins the JavaScript code
//var saved = localStorage.getItem("saved") || "[]";
var saved = "[]";
var coolWords = JSON.parse(saved); 


function doEverything(aString) {
  var bString = aString.split(" ");
  var finalResult = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < bString.length; i++) {
    if (coolWords.indexOf(bString[i]) < 0) // added this bit..
      coolWords.push(bString[i]);
  };

  newList = coolWords.slice();

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var hey = newList.splice( Math.floor( Math.random() * newList.length ), 1) [0];
    finalResult.push(" " + hey);
  }; // [0] is used so finalResult receives only strings and not whole arrays with only one string in each array.
  
  //localStorage.setItem("saved",JSON.stringify(coolWords));
  return ("Hey, the words are " + finalResult[0] + ", " + finalResult[1] + " and " + finalResult[2] + ".");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="button">
    <input type="text" id="userInputField" value="">
    <button class="button">Magic</button>
  </div>

  <div id="userOutput">
    <p class="userOutput">test</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your code! Actually, I was inspired to accomplish everything and without issues by reducing the code to only one loop and two arrays, not 4. :D The JSON part I will look more into these days and see how it fits within the bigger picture.